# Julia Interpolation Error with $-sign in Pkg-dir() Path in Pkg.build()

Tags: string, julia

Using a Pkg.dir() Path with the following String-representation:

```
"\\\\SUBDNxyz.companynet.ch\\Service\$\\Programme\\"
```

I get an error whenever I run Pkg.build():

```
ERROR: syntax: invalid interpolation syntax: "$\"
ERROR: Build process failed.
Stacktrace:
 [1] build!(::Array{String,1}, ::Set{Any}, ::String) at .\pkg\entry.jl:629
 [2] build!(::Array{String,1}, ::Dict{Any,Any}, ::Set{Any}) at .\pkg\entry.jl:637
 [3] build(::Array{String,1}) at .\pkg\entry.jl:652
 [4] (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##3#6{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#build,Tuple{Array{String,1}}})() at .\pkg\dir.jl:33
 [5] cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##3#6{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#build,Tuple{Array{String,1}}}, ::String) at .\file.jl:59
 [6] withenv(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#5{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#build,Tuple{Array{String,1}},String}, ::Pair{String,String}, ::Vararg{Pair{String,String},N} where N) at .\env.jl:157
 [7] #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Array{String,1}, ::Vararg{Array{String,1},N} where N) at .\pkg\dir.jl:32
 [8] build(::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at .\pkg\pkg.jl:254
```

How can I go around this error? Is there a way to represent $ differently than with "\$"?

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.6.3
Commit d55cadc350* (2018-05-28 20:20 UTC)
DEBUG build
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2687W v3 @ 3.10GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Nehalem)
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.9.1 (ORCJIT, haswell)
```

EDIT: 
The problem does not occur for all Packages, e.g. Pkg.build("Missings") works fine. Packages as "PyCall" or "DataFrames" cause that error. In addition, the representation of the String doesn't matter. I also tried `raw"\\SUBDNxyz.companynet.ch\Service$\Programme"` etc.

Comment: Could you please share the output of `versioninfo()`?

Comment: for your second question (is there a way to represent $ differently than with \$) there is: `\u24`, not sure it'd help though (hard to tell without being able to reproduce the error)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. Not the representation of the string is the problem, but the fact the following substring "$\" is included in the path.